# QGIS - exporting shapefile to convert to .JSON for use in PowerBI

Tags: qgis, shapefile, mapping, power-bi

I'm trying to export a shapefile I've been using in QGIS for use in PowerBI because PowerBI only supports .JSON extensions. So I've been converting them with mapshaper.org. This is my shapefile result in PowerBI:

[image: m]

I've tried a couple of things:

- Exported my "custom" .SHP file as a .GeoJSON (I say custom because I deleted the geographies I did not need in QGIS Attributetable - maybe this is causing the problem?). I then converted it in mapshaper.org to .JSON. The shape appears fine in the mapshaper.org preview, but it's wonky when I upload it to PowerBI as per my attached image above.
- Converted the original shapefile I downloaded from StatsCan. This has all geographies (most of which I don't use). When I load this into PowerBI nothing happens. It basically hangs the program. The file is roughly 92MB. Again, when I'm converting use mapshaper.org the map appears correct.

I know this a GIS forum and not PowerBI so I don't expect help on that end.

Answer (score -2):

The problem was with the CRS. Solution [here](https://dataveld.com/2016/09/01/overcoming-potential-power-bi-shape-map-rendering-issues/).

Comment: Saying nothing in the answer and linking to a URL which in the future might be broken is a poor habit...